# How to install ODBC driver in azure DevOps built pipeline to run a script on Azure ML compute?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, mlops

I am running a Python script to connect to my Azure SQL db in a DevOps built pipeline. I am attaching the azure ML compute to the script while running it from DevOps using azure CLI. But how can I install the ODBC driver on the Azure agent? or is the docker image I need to install which is being called while submitting the script in cli?

Comment: Have you tried using a pre-built image with the ODBC driver pre-installed? If not, have you tried installing it through a Dockerfile?

Comment: This looks like the answer you (and I) are looking for: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/827#issuecomment-807989458